# How to find sum of all objects for some key in array of dictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `Array` of `Dictionaries`.

```
NSArray *myDicionariesArrey = ( object 1: { keyToCulc: 30 } , object 2: { keyToCulc: 40 } )
```

How to find sum of all objects for `keyToCulc` key in the array, with simple command? 
**(30 + 40 = 70)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int sum = [myDicionariesArrey valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.keyToCulc"];
```

NB: Untested, written from memory.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have an array of `NSDictionary`s

```
NSArray *myDicionariesArray = @[@{@"keyToCulc": @30},  @{@"keyToCulc": @40}];
```

The of sum `keyToCulc` values would be

```
NSNumber *sum = [myDicionariesArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.keyToCulc"];
```

(Your `myDicionariesArrey` was probably written in a pseudo code, so I was not sure if I got the structure of the dictionaries correct)